# Retokenize email address

Tags: python, nltk, tokenize

Is there a way to retokenize email addresses so that they are email addresses again? In the code I am using now (see below), if I give as input `mobydick123@gmail.com` I get as output `mobydick123 @ gmail.com`.

```
from nltk.tokenize.treebank import TreebankWordDetokenizer
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize
from itertools import groupby 
import spacy

input_sent = 'Herman Melvilles email is mobydick123@gmail.com'

tokens = word_tokenize(input_sent)
print(tokens)

myList = list(filter((']').__ne__, tokens))
myList = list(filter(('[').__ne__, myList))

res = [i[0] for i in groupby(myList)]
my_list = list(map(lambda item: item.replace("W_NLP_PERSON", "[W_NLP_PERSON]").replace('W_NLP_DATE', '[W_NLP_DATE]').replace('W_NLP_IMEI_HARDWARE_ID', '[W_NLP_IMEI_HARDWARE_ID]').replace('W_NLP_IP_ADDRESS', '[W_NLP_IP_ADDRESS]'), res))
my_list = TreebankWordDetokenizer().detokenize(my_list)

print(my_list)
```

Comment: so given your list, ```my_list```, your expected outcome is ```Herman Melvilles email is mobydick123@gmail.com```?

Comment: Yes, that is what I would like to get.

Comment: Why are you importing spaCy if you aren't using it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the last 3 elements of your list will always be name + @ + domain, i.e:

```
>>> my_list.split()[-3:]
['mobydick123', '@', 'gmail.com']
```

You could split your list based on spaces and join two joins.

```
elements = my_list.split()
>>> print(' '.join(elements[:-3]),''.join(elements[-3:]))

Herman Melvilles email is mobydick123@gmail.com
```

The first part joins with a delimiter space, and the second part joins with no delimiter which puts the email together.  Hinging on the assumption that the last 3 elements will be the email, which is a solid assumption as this is the case usually, this should work.

Comment: Thanks for that! I thought about it but I didn't know where to start implementing it. Actually your solution is pretty easy to generalize by searching for "@" and then taking the tokens before and after that.

Comment: Welcome, Yeah this is quite a straightforward approach. Perhaps there is a more elegant way though

Comment: I also wonder this is not covered in standard tokenization packages. Will keep looking.